# How to implement like/dislike button (for logged-in users) in django using AJAX

Tags: python, django, ajax, post

I tried implementing Like(for those users who didn't like) and Dislike(for users who already liked the post) buttons but I could not get it to work. I tried looking some past questions but I could not solve the issue. If someone has done this before, kindly help.

my blog/models.py for Post model

```
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='likes', blank=True)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    def total_likes(self):
        return self.likes.count()
```

my blog/views.py

```
def post_detail(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    is_liked = False
    if post.likes.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
        is_liked = True
    return render(request, 'blog/post_detail.html', {'post': post, 'is_liked': is_liked, 'total_likes': post.total_likes(), })

def like_post(request):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=request.POST.get('id'))
    is_liked = False
    if post.likes.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
        post.likes.remove(request.user)
        is_liked = False
    else:
        post.likes.add(request.user)
        is_liked = True
    context = {
        'post': post,
        'is_liked': is_liked,
        'total_likes': post.total_likes(),
    }
    if request.is_ajax():
        html = render_to_string('blog/like_section.html', context, request=request)
        return JsonResponse({'form': html})
```

my HTML and AJAX code (this section is present in post_detail.html)

```
    <div id="like-section">
        {% include 'blog/like_section.html' %}
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascirpt">
        $('#like').click(function(){
            var pk = $(this).attr('value');
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: "like_post",
                data: {
                    'id':pk,
                },
                success: function(response){
                    $('#like-section').html(response['form'])
                },
            });
        });
    </script>
```

like-section.html is a separate template :-

```
<p>{{ total_likes }} Like{{ total_likes|pluralize }}</p>
{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
<form action="{% url 'like_post' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% if is_liked %}
        <button type="submit" id="like" name="post_id" value="{{ post.id }}" class="btn btn-danger">Dislike</button>
    {% else %}
        <button type="submit" id="like" name="post_id" value="{{ post.id }}" class="btn btn-primary">Like</button>
    {% endif %}
</form>
{% endif %}
```

my main project folders urls.py code :-

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('accounts/login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
    path('accounts/logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(next_page='/'), name='logout'),
    path('', include('blog.urls')),
]
```

my blog app's urls.py code :-

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.post_list, name='post_list'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/', views.post_detail, name='post_detail'),
    path('post/new/', views.post_new, name='post_new'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/edit/', views.post_edit, name='post_edit'),
    path('drafts/', views.post_draft_list, name='post_draft_list'),
    path('post/<pk>/publish/', views.post_publish, name='post_publish'),
    path('post/<pk>/remove/', views.post_remove, name='post_remove'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/comment/', views.add_comment_to_post, name='add_comment_to_post'),
    path('comment/<int:pk>/approve/', views.comment_approve, name='comment_approve'),
    path('comment/<int:pk>/remove/', views.comment_remove, name='comment_remove'),
    path('like/', views.like_post, name="like_post"),
]
```

Screenshot of the directories
[image]

Now, the error which I am getting on running this on localhost :-
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm writing this as a reference for any one how is going to run into this

make sure in your base.html you have the following

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(event){
                $(document).on('click', '#like', function(event){
                    event.preventDefault();
                    var pk = $(this).attr('value');
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: '{% url "like_post" %}',
                        data: {
                            'id': pk,
                            'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}'
                        },
                        datatype: 'json',
                        success: function(response){
                            $('#like-section').html(response['form'])

                        },
                        error: function(rs, e){
                            console.log(rs.responseText);
                        },
                    });
                });
            });
</script>
</body>
```

Make sure your view looks like this

```
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect, JsonResponse
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from django.utils import timezone
from .models import Post



def post_list(request):
    posts = Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('published_date')
    return render(request, 'blog/post_list.html', {'posts': posts})
    
def post_detail(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    is_liked = False
    if post.likes.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
       is_liked = True
    return render(request, 'blog/post_detail.html', {'post': post, 'is_liked': is_liked, 'total_likes': post.total_likes(), })   
    
 
def like_post(request):

    post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=request.POST.get('id'))    
    is_liked = False
    if post.likes.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
        post.likes.remove(request.user)
        is_liked = False
    else:
        post.likes.add(request.user)
        is_liked = True
    context = {
        'post': post,
        'is_liked': is_liked,
        'total_likes': post.total_likes(),
    }
    if request.is_ajax():
        html = render_to_string('blog/like_section.html', context, request=request)
        return JsonResponse({'form': html})
```

Answer (score 0):

the correct AJAX code is

```
            $(document).ready(function(event){
                $(document).on('click', '#like', function(event){
                    event.preventDefault();
                    var pk = $(this).attr('value');
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: '{% url "like_post" %}',
                        data: {
                            'id': pk,
                            'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}'
                        },
                        success: function(response){
                            $('#like-section').html(response['form'])
                        },
                        error: function(rs, e){
                            console.log(rs.responseText);
                        },
                    });
                });
            });
```